# How to build gdal with MBTiles drive?

Tags: gdal, mbtiles, tile-map-service

I've built GDAL so many times but I'm not know how to add [MBTiles Driver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mbtiles.html) support.

The source used was http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.1.3/ .
But after build I still unable to read or write mbtiles files.

```
[root@localhost geo]# gdalinfo  Test.mbtiles
ERROR 4: `Test.mbtiles' not recognized as a supported file format.

gdalinfo failed - unable to open 'Test.mbtiles'.
```

## Some additional info:

### Version:

> [root@localhost ~]# gdal-config --version
>   2.1.3

### dep-libs

> [root@localhost ~]# gdal-config --dep-libs
>   -ljpeg -lpng -L/usr/lib64 -lpq -lz -lpthread -lm -lrt -ldl -lpcre -lxml2 -lz -lm -ldl

### Formats

> [root@localhost ~]# gdal-config --formats gxf gtiff hfa aigrid aaigrid
>   ceos ceos2 iso8211 xpm sdts raw dted mem jdem envisat elas fit vrt
>   usgsdem l1b nitf bmp airsar rs2 ilwis rmf leveller sgi srtmhgt idrisi
>   gsg ingr ers jaxapalsar dimap gff cosar pds adrg coasp tsx terragen
>   blx msgn til r northwood saga xyz hf2 kmlsuperoverlay ctg e00grid zmap
>   ngsgeoid iris map cals safe sentinel2 mrf grib bsb gif jpeg png
>   pcraster pcidsk rik ozi pdf postgisraster arg

### gdal translate formats:

```
[root@localhost ~]# gdal_translate --formats
Supported Formats:
  VRT -raster- (rw+v): Virtual Raster
  GTiff -raster- (rw+vs): GeoTIFF
  NITF -raster- (rw+vs): National Imagery Transmission Format
  RPFTOC -raster- (rovs): Raster Product Format TOC format
  ECRGTOC -raster- (rovs): ECRG TOC format
  HFA -raster- (rw+v): Erdas Imagine Images (.img)
  SAR_CEOS -raster- (rov): CEOS SAR Image
  CEOS -raster- (rov): CEOS Image
  JAXAPALSAR -raster- (rov): JAXA PALSAR Product Reader (Level 1.1/1.5)
  GFF -raster- (rov): Ground-based SAR Applications Testbed File Format (.gff)
  ELAS -raster- (rw+v): ELAS
  AIG -raster- (rov): Arc/Info Binary Grid
  AAIGrid -raster- (rwv): Arc/Info ASCII Grid
  GRASSASCIIGrid -raster- (rov): GRASS ASCII Grid
  SDTS -raster- (rov): SDTS Raster
  DTED -raster- (rwv): DTED Elevation Raster
  PNG -raster- (rwv): Portable Network Graphics
  JPEG -raster- (rwv): JPEG JFIF
  MEM -raster- (rw+): In Memory Raster
  JDEM -raster- (rov): Japanese DEM (.mem)
  GIF -raster- (rwv): Graphics Interchange Format (.gif)
  BIGGIF -raster- (rov): Graphics Interchange Format (.gif)
  ESAT -raster- (rov): Envisat Image Format
  BSB -raster- (rov): Maptech BSB Nautical Charts
  XPM -raster- (rwv): X11 PixMap Format
  BMP -raster- (rw+v): MS Windows Device Independent Bitmap
  DIMAP -raster- (rov): SPOT DIMAP
  AirSAR -raster- (rov): AirSAR Polarimetric Image
  RS2 -raster- (ros): RadarSat 2 XML Product
  SAFE -raster- (rov): Sentinel-1 SAR SAFE Product
  PCIDSK -raster,vector- (rw+v): PCIDSK Database File
  PCRaster -raster- (rw+): PCRaster Raster File
  ILWIS -raster- (rw+v): ILWIS Raster Map
  SGI -raster- (rw+): SGI Image File Format 1.0
  SRTMHGT -raster- (rwv): SRTMHGT File Format
  Leveller -raster- (rw+): Leveller heightfield
  Terragen -raster- (rw+): Terragen heightfield
  ISIS3 -raster- (rov): USGS Astrogeology ISIS cube (Version 3)
  ISIS2 -raster- (rw+v): USGS Astrogeology ISIS cube (Version 2)
  PDS -raster- (rov): NASA Planetary Data System
  VICAR -raster- (rov): MIPL VICAR file
  TIL -raster- (rov): EarthWatch .TIL
  ERS -raster- (rw+v): ERMapper .ers Labelled
  L1B -raster- (rovs): NOAA Polar Orbiter Level 1b Data Set
  FIT -raster- (rwv): FIT Image
  GRIB -raster- (rov): GRIdded Binary (.grb)
  RMF -raster- (rw+v): Raster Matrix Format
  MSGN -raster- (ro): EUMETSAT Archive native (.nat)
  RST -raster- (rw+v): Idrisi Raster A.1
  INGR -raster- (rw+v): Intergraph Raster
  GSAG -raster- (rwv): Golden Software ASCII Grid (.grd)
  GSBG -raster- (rw+v): Golden Software Binary Grid (.grd)
  GS7BG -raster- (rw+v): Golden Software 7 Binary Grid (.grd)
  COSAR -raster- (rov): COSAR Annotated Binary Matrix (TerraSAR-X)
  TSX -raster- (rov): TerraSAR-X Product
  COASP -raster- (ro): DRDC COASP SAR Processor Raster
  R -raster- (rwv): R Object Data Store
  MAP -raster- (rov): OziExplorer .MAP
  KMLSUPEROVERLAY -raster- (rwv): Kml Super Overlay
  PDF -raster,vector- (w+): Geospatial PDF
  CALS -raster- (rw): CALS (Type 1)
  SENTINEL2 -raster- (rovs): Sentinel 2
  MRF -raster- (rw+v): Meta Raster Format
  PNM -raster- (rw+v): Portable Pixmap Format (netpbm)
  DOQ1 -raster- (rov): USGS DOQ (Old Style)
  DOQ2 -raster- (rov): USGS DOQ (New Style)
  GenBin -raster- (rov): Generic Binary (.hdr Labelled)
  PAux -raster- (rw+): PCI .aux Labelled
  MFF -raster- (rw+v): Vexcel MFF Raster
  MFF2 -raster- (rw+): Vexcel MFF2 (HKV) Raster
  FujiBAS -raster- (ro): Fuji BAS Scanner Image
  GSC -raster- (rov): GSC Geogrid
  FAST -raster- (rov): EOSAT FAST Format
  BT -raster- (rw+v): VTP .bt (Binary Terrain) 1.3 Format
  LAN -raster- (rw+v): Erdas .LAN/.GIS
  CPG -raster- (ro): Convair PolGASP
  IDA -raster- (rw+v): Image Data and Analysis
  NDF -raster- (rov): NLAPS Data Format
  EIR -raster- (rov): Erdas Imagine Raw
  DIPEx -raster- (rov): DIPEx
  LCP -raster- (rwv): FARSITE v.4 Landscape File (.lcp)
  GTX -raster- (rw+v): NOAA Vertical Datum .GTX
  LOSLAS -raster- (rov): NADCON .los/.las Datum Grid Shift
  NTv2 -raster- (rw+vs): NTv2 Datum Grid Shift
  CTable2 -raster- (rw+v): CTable2 Datum Grid Shift
  ACE2 -raster- (rov): ACE2
  SNODAS -raster- (rov): Snow Data Assimilation System
  KRO -raster- (rw+v): KOLOR Raw
  ROI_PAC -raster- (rw+v): ROI_PAC raster
  ENVI -raster- (rw+v): ENVI .hdr Labelled
  EHdr -raster- (rw+v): ESRI .hdr Labelled
  ISCE -raster- (rw+v): ISCE raster
  ARG -raster- (rwv): Azavea Raster Grid format
  RIK -raster- (rov): Swedish Grid RIK (.rik)
  USGSDEM -raster- (rwv): USGS Optional ASCII DEM (and CDED)
  GXF -raster- (ro): GeoSoft Grid Exchange Format
  NWT_GRD -raster- (rov): Northwood Numeric Grid Format .grd/.tab
  NWT_GRC -raster- (rov): Northwood Classified Grid Format .grc/.tab
  ADRG -raster- (rw+vs): ARC Digitized Raster Graphics
  SRP -raster- (rovs): Standard Raster Product (ASRP/USRP)
  BLX -raster- (rwv): Magellan topo (.blx)
  PostGISRaster -raster- (rws): PostGIS Raster driver
  SAGA -raster- (rw+v): SAGA GIS Binary Grid (.sdat)
  XYZ -raster- (rwv): ASCII Gridded XYZ
  HF2 -raster- (rwv): HF2/HFZ heightfield raster
  OZI -raster- (rov): OziExplorer Image File
  CTG -raster- (rov): USGS LULC Composite Theme Grid
  E00GRID -raster- (rov): Arc/Info Export E00 GRID
  ZMap -raster- (rwv): ZMap Plus Grid
  NGSGEOID -raster- (rov): NOAA NGS Geoid Height Grids
  IRIS -raster- (rov): IRIS data (.PPI, .CAPPi etc)
```

### Config params:

```
./configure  --with-threads \
            --with-libtiff \
            --with-ogr \
            --with-geos \
            --without-libtool \
            --with-libz=internal \
            --with-libtiff \
            --with-geotiff \
            --with-gif \
            --with-pg \
            --with-grass \
            --with-libgrass \
            --with-cfitsio \
            --with-pcraster \
            --with-netcdf \
            --with-png \
            --with-jpeg \
            --with-odbc \
            --with-curl \
            --with-sqlite3 \
            --with-idb \
            --with-sde \
            --with-perl \
            --with-php \
            --with-ruby \
            --with-python \
            --with-ogpython \
            --with-hide-internal-symbols
```

Comment: Sqlite seems to required. Do you have that in your build?

Comment: From gdal help pages: "GDAL/OGR must be compiled with OGR SQLite driver support, and JPEG and PNG drivers."

Comment: please add the config settings used (gdal-config --dep-libs for example)

Comment: Edited with some extra info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way, it helped me.

Append repository for libspatialite5 and libgeos-c1 to source list (if it does not exist)

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid main universe
```

then install dependencies

```
sudo apt update
```

libspatialite5 depend on libgeos-c1 (>= 3.4.2), so in my case it is

```
sudo apt install libspatialite5 libgeos-c1 libspatialite-dev  spatialite-bin sqlite3
```

cd to your GDAL folder

```
$ cd gdal-2.1.3/
```

make configuration

```
./configure --with-spatialite --with-sqlite
```

run

```
make
```

and then

```
sudo make install
```

Thanks [user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30184/user30184) and [Dmitriy Litvinov](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/63785/dmitriy-litvinov). More information about this case you can find [Convert .tif to .mbtiles using python/GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230725/convert-tif-to-mbtiles-using-python-gdal)