# Convert .tif to .mbtiles using python/GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, mbtiles

I have a tiff file and I'd like to convert it to mbtiles using python script.
In general, I need just select tiff file and convert it to mbtiles to upload it on the map (from python script) but got stuck on the conversion.

I've tried https://github.com/developmentseed/gdal2mb and https://github.com/crschmidt/raster2mb, but as a result I got broken mbtiles (I loaded mbtiles file into QGIS and nothing was shown). In second github link is written :
Restrictions
Because mbtiles is limited in the profiles it supports, it is only possible to use it to create tilesets from imagery that covers the entire world; imagery which is smaller will create a database successfully, but it will not be in the necessary spherical mercator profile. If you wish to build a tileset, you must first make your image cover the entire world.

Also, gdal_translate rise an error Output driver `MBTILES' not recognised.
Are there any more python script for this? Or there is the way to solve issue with raster2mb and gdal_translate?

### My GDAL version: GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01

$ gdalinfo 2.tif

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 2.tif
Size is 11418, 7692
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["Google Maps Global Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",0],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","900913"]]
Origin = (34.610612291795853,31.533709086005583)
Pixel Size = (0.000015441030299,-0.000015441030299)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=820
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=820
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  34.6106123,  31.5337091) (  0d 0' 1.12"E,  0d 0' 1.02"N)
Lower Left  (  34.6106123,  31.4149367) (  0d 0' 1.12"E,  0d 0' 1.02"N)
Upper Right (  34.7869180,  31.5337091) (  0d 0' 1.12"E,  0d 0' 1.02"N)
Lower Right (  34.7869180,  31.4149367) (  0d 0' 1.12"E,  0d 0' 1.02"N)
Center      (  34.6987651,  31.4743229) (  0d 0' 1.12"E,  0d 0' 1.02"N)
Band 1 Block=11418x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=11418x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=11418x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

$ gdalinfo --formats

Supported Formats:

```
VRT -raster- (rw+v): Virtual Raster
GTiff -raster- (rw+vs): GeoTIFF
NITF -raster- (rw+vs): National Imagery Transmission Format
RPFTOC -raster- (rovs): Raster Product Format TOC format
ECRGTOC -raster- (rovs): ECRG TOC format
HFA -raster- (rw+v): Erdas Imagine Images (.img)
SAR_CEOS -raster- (rov): CEOS SAR Image
CEOS -raster- (rov): CEOS Image
JAXAPALSAR -raster- (rov): JAXA PALSAR Product Reader (Level 1.1/1.5)
GFF -raster- (rov): Ground-based SAR Applications Testbed File Format (.gff)
ELAS -raster- (rw+v): ELAS
AIG -raster- (rov): Arc/Info Binary Grid
AAIGrid -raster- (rwv): Arc/Info ASCII Grid
GRASSASCIIGrid -raster- (rov): GRASS ASCII Grid
SDTS -raster- (rov): SDTS Raster
DTED -raster- (rwv): DTED Elevation Raster
PNG -raster- (rwv): Portable Network Graphics
JPEG -raster- (rwv): JPEG JFIF
MEM -raster- (rw+): In Memory Raster
JDEM -raster- (rov): Japanese DEM (.mem)
GIF -raster- (rwv): Graphics Interchange Format (.gif)
BIGGIF -raster- (rov): Graphics Interchange Format (.gif)
ESAT -raster- (rov): Envisat Image Format
BSB -raster- (rov): Maptech BSB Nautical Charts
XPM -raster- (rwv): X11 PixMap Format
BMP -raster- (rw+v): MS Windows Device Independent Bitmap
DIMAP -raster- (rov): SPOT DIMAP
AirSAR -raster- (rov): AirSAR Polarimetric Image
RS2 -raster- (ros): RadarSat 2 XML Product
SAFE -raster- (rov): Sentinel-1 SAR SAFE Product
PCIDSK -raster,vector- (rw+v): PCIDSK Database File
PCRaster -raster- (rw+): PCRaster Raster File
ILWIS -raster- (rw+v): ILWIS Raster Map
SGI -raster- (rw+): SGI Image File Format 1.0
SRTMHGT -raster- (rwv): SRTMHGT File Format
Leveller -raster- (rw+): Leveller heightfield
Terragen -raster- (rw+): Terragen heightfield
ISIS3 -raster- (rov): USGS Astrogeology ISIS cube (Version 3)
ISIS2 -raster- (rw+v): USGS Astrogeology ISIS cube (Version 2)
PDS -raster- (rov): NASA Planetary Data System
VICAR -raster- (rov): MIPL VICAR file
TIL -raster- (rov): EarthWatch .TIL
ERS -raster- (rw+v): ERMapper .ers Labelled
L1B -raster- (rovs): NOAA Polar Orbiter Level 1b Data Set
FIT -raster- (rwv): FIT Image
GRIB -raster- (rov): GRIdded Binary (.grb)
RMF -raster- (rw+v): Raster Matrix Format
MSGN -raster- (ro): EUMETSAT Archive native (.nat)
RST -raster- (rw+v): Idrisi Raster A.1
INGR -raster- (rw+v): Intergraph Raster
GSAG -raster- (rwv): Golden Software ASCII Grid (.grd)
GSBG -raster- (rw+v): Golden Software Binary Grid (.grd)
GS7BG -raster- (rw+v): Golden Software 7 Binary Grid (.grd)
COSAR -raster- (rov): COSAR Annotated Binary Matrix (TerraSAR-X)
TSX -raster- (rov): TerraSAR-X Product
COASP -raster- (ro): DRDC COASP SAR Processor Raster
R -raster- (rwv): R Object Data Store
MAP -raster- (rov): OziExplorer .MAP
KMLSUPEROVERLAY -raster- (rwv): Kml Super Overlay
PDF -raster,vector- (w+): Geospatial PDF
CALS -raster- (rw): CALS (Type 1)
SENTINEL2 -raster- (rovs): Sentinel 2
MRF -raster- (rw+v): Meta Raster Format
PNM -raster- (rw+v): Portable Pixmap Format (netpbm)
DOQ1 -raster- (rov): USGS DOQ (Old Style)
DOQ2 -raster- (rov): USGS DOQ (New Style)
GenBin -raster- (rov): Generic Binary (.hdr Labelled)
PAux -raster- (rw+): PCI .aux Labelled
MFF -raster- (rw+v): Vexcel MFF Raster
MFF2 -raster- (rw+): Vexcel MFF2 (HKV) Raster
FujiBAS -raster- (ro): Fuji BAS Scanner Image
GSC -raster- (rov): GSC Geogrid
FAST -raster- (rov): EOSAT FAST Format
BT -raster- (rw+v): VTP .bt (Binary Terrain) 1.3 Format
LAN -raster- (rw+v): Erdas .LAN/.GIS
CPG -raster- (ro): Convair PolGASP
IDA -raster- (rw+v): Image Data and Analysis
NDF -raster- (rov): NLAPS Data Format
EIR -raster- (rov): Erdas Imagine Raw
DIPEx -raster- (rov): DIPEx
LCP -raster- (rwv): FARSITE v.4 Landscape File (.lcp)
GTX -raster- (rw+v): NOAA Vertical Datum .GTX
LOSLAS -raster- (rov): NADCON .los/.las Datum Grid Shift
NTv2 -raster- (rw+vs): NTv2 Datum Grid Shift
CTable2 -raster- (rw+v): CTable2 Datum Grid Shift
ACE2 -raster- (rov): ACE2
SNODAS -raster- (rov): Snow Data Assimilation System
KRO -raster- (rw+v): KOLOR Raw
ROI_PAC -raster- (rw+v): ROI_PAC raster
ENVI -raster- (rw+v): ENVI .hdr Labelled
EHdr -raster- (rw+v): ESRI .hdr Labelled
ISCE -raster- (rw+v): ISCE raster
ARG -raster- (rwv): Azavea Raster Grid format
RIK -raster- (rov): Swedish Grid RIK (.rik)
USGSDEM -raster- (rwv): USGS Optional ASCII DEM (and CDED)
GXF -raster- (ro): GeoSoft Grid Exchange Format
NWT_GRD -raster- (rov): Northwood Numeric Grid Format .grd/.tab
NWT_GRC -raster- (rov): Northwood Classified Grid Format .grc/.tab
ADRG -raster- (rw+vs): ARC Digitized Raster Graphics
SRP -raster- (rovs): Standard Raster Product (ASRP/USRP)
BLX -raster- (rwv): Magellan topo (.blx)
SAGA -raster- (rw+v): SAGA GIS Binary Grid (.sdat)
XYZ -raster- (rwv): ASCII Gridded XYZ
HF2 -raster- (rwv): HF2/HFZ heightfield raster
OZI -raster- (rov): OziExplorer Image File
CTG -raster- (rov): USGS LULC Composite Theme Grid
E00GRID -raster- (rov): Arc/Info Export E00 GRID
ZMap -raster- (rwv): ZMap Plus Grid
NGSGEOID -raster- (rov): NOAA NGS Geoid Height Grids
IRIS -raster- (rov): IRIS data (.PPI, .CAPPi etc)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are few methods to do this:

1. You can try [rio-mbtiles](https://github.com/mapbox/rio-mbtiles) or [gdal2mbtiles](https://github.com/bolshoydi/gdal2mbtiles) to write your input raster directly into *mbtiles*.
2. GDAL library originaly provides [gdal2tiles.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html) script to generate directories with TMS tiles. Also you can use [gdal2tilesp](https://github.com/bolshoydi/gdal2tilesp) with multiprocessing support. After tiles were generated you can load them into *mbtiles* database using [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil).

P.S. Starting with GDAL 2.1, the MBTiles driver has creation and write support for MBTiles datasets. So you can use [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) to generate mbtiles with base zoom level (automaticaly defined). And then use [gdaladdo](http://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html) to generate overviews.

Comment: The gdal2mbtiles link is dead now, but I see https://github.com/ecometrica/gdal2mbtiles- is that the same?

Answer (score 2):

Gdal_translate is all you need and usage is documented in http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mbtiles.html.

However, you need GDAL version that is compiled with MBTiles and SQlite as MBTiles depends on that. Check if you have the driver with

```
gdalinfo --formats
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But with gdal_translate I have issue like http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227982/how-to-build-gdal-with-mbtiles-drive . On my ubuntu GDAL does not support MBTILES format. Do you know step-by-step instruction how to add SQlite support to GDAl 2.1.3?
Could you please help with an example of creation mbtiles because there http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mbtiles.html not clear enough how to achieve  .mbtiles from common .tiff file. On second PC, where is OS Windows, GDAL supports mbtiles, but rise an error: "Could not find appropriate zoom level"

Comment: Show gdalinfo from the original image and exact command that you used and I can see if I find something. I do not compile myself so I can't help with that. Ask from gdal-dev mailing lists.

Comment: Have you tried to compile with `--with-sqlite3 \`? It might be enough for bringing the MBTiles support as it does for geopackage rasters http://erouault.blogspot.fi/2014/12/gdal-geopackage-raster-support.html

Comment: I've added raster info and supported formats. If any additional information should be added, please let me know.

Comment: So you do not have MBTiles driver. Before you have that you can't do anything. When you have it you will see `MBTiles -raster- (rw+v): MBTiles`.

Comment: Yes, i tried to say that my gdal didn't have SQlite support. But I can't figure out how to compile gdal with SQlite. Do you know docs where this instruction can be present? Or do you know any other way how to create mbtile using python?

Comment: I suggest to ask either from gdal-dev or from stackoverflow about how to compile GDAL with SQLite and if MBTiles comes automatically after that. Come back then. In the "configure" file in GDAL trunk SQLite is actually turned on https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/configure.

Comment: I was building GDAL with MBTiles and spatialite support using this article [spatialite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.3.1/how_to_build_libspatialite.html). Then added path to binaries in GDAL **nmake.opt** file to SQLITE_INC parametr.

Comment: @Dmitriy Litvinov Could you please explain which path should be added to nmake.opt?
I find out two entries in this file:
`#SQLITE_INC=-IN:\pkg\sqlite-win32`
`#SQLITE_INC=-IC:\osgeo4w\include -DHAVE_SPATIALITE -DSPATIALITE_AMALGAMATION`
But both point to Windows. What should I add on my Ubuntu?

Comment: @Davion Sorry, i didn't notice that you are on Ubuntu. You actually don't need nmake.opt. First run `apt-get install libspatialite-dev libspatialite5 spatialite-bin sqlite3`. Then ./configure --with-spatialite --with-sqlite in the GDAL source folder. then run _make_ and then _sudo make install_.

Comment: @Dmitriy Litvinov Thank you, it worked for me (with little changes).
`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
add
`deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid main universe`
`sudo apt update`
libspatialite5 depend on libgeos-c1 (>= 3.4.2), so in my case it is:
`sudo apt install libspatialite5 libgeos-c1` . But now I've got an error: `$ gdal_translate 1.tif 1.mbtiles -of MBTILES
Input file size is 11420, 7688
ERROR 1: Could not find an appropriate zoom level` . What should I do to tiff to set zoom levels? (e.g. -z 10-18)

Comment: @Davion `gdal_translate` should automatically determ the appropriate zoom level (so called _base level_). Then using [gdaladdo](http://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html) you can generate _overview levels_ (tiles). Also you can try my [gdal2mbtiles](https://github.com/bolshoydi/gdal2mbtiles) script (it in developing stage now). On linux it works only under python3 and if in `if __name_=='__main__':' add 'multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` before _main_ function call

Comment: @DmitriyLitvinov Great job. Could you please help me: when I run on Windows `python.exe dal2mbtiles.py tif_4326.tif -z 10-18 -a 0 output.mbtiles` get an error http://dpaste.com/2Q70GPQ

Comment: Perhaps mismatch in your GDAL python bindings and your python version 3.5.

Comment: On Windows I used GDAL-2.1.3-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl and installed OSGeo4W . Is it correct way to install gdal?

Comment: Do you know clear installation manual for gdal package to avoid mismatches like that?I need it to work, at least on Windows.

Comment: @Davion your GDAL is fine, because it even  wouldn't start base tiling if GDAL was corrupted. I've tested gdal2mbtiles on _Windows Python2.7.10 x32 \x64 and Python 3.4 x64 GDAL 2.0.1\2.1.0\2.1.3_ and i hadn't got such error. I afraid your _input.tif_ is "corrupted" because _gdal_translate_ doesn't work with your _input.tif_ too. Maybe  sometghing wrong with SRS?

Comment: Maybe, initial files are .tif without srs and .tfw. I do `$ gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 ~/projects/1.tif new_4326.tif` and then check `$ gdalinfo new_4326.tif`, info looks good. Is this way correct or I should do some another transformation?

Comment: @Davion Looks clearly. Is your **new_4326.tif** opens properly (i mean without any warns or errors about srs or other metadata) in QGIS? Could you publish in a cloud your new_4326.tif?

Comment: @DmitriyLitvinov Could you please provide me with method how can I share rasters?

Comment: @Davion try this http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/drive/

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-nUbIkhbuq6ZVNKRVppbTRXYUk/view?usp=sharing
There are 3 files: initial 1.tif, 1.twf and transformed file new_4326.tif. When I open new_4326.tif in QGIS it opens well (no messages appear).

Comment: @Davion it's realy strange, but i get the same error about illegal buffer. Here the [result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ieW5ZKY2lXcGx6LUdWUFg4dUk/view?usp=sharing) mbtiles. I've made it using [gdal2tilesp](https://github.com/bolshoydi/gdal2tilesp) and [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil)

Comment: @DmitriyLitvinov Great result, this is exactly what I need. I will try to reach this result using gdal2tilesp and mbutil. But the tiles are slightly shifted to the lower right side (you can try to open the original raster and mbtiles in QGIS).

Comment: @Davion it is whell known  [bug](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5785)

Comment: Bug was fixed one and a half years ago. Are you @Davion having so old GDAL? Check with gdalinfo --version.

Comment: I was talking about the mbtiles, which was put by @DmitriyLitvinov. My GDAL version is 2.1.3, but today I have not had the opportunity to run the process on a working PC. I want to reinstall from scratch all libraries and python.

Comment: Thanks, @DmitriyLitvinov, the method you suggested works in my case (using gdal2tilesp and mbutil). 

I read about the bug, but does it make sense to make changes to the .cpp file or to convert it to EPSG: 3857 (will it be correctly displayed in this coordinate system)?

Comment: @DmitriyLitvinov Could you write answer as your comment above (I've made it using gdal2tilesp and mbutil), I will accept it.